# Setting correct headers for uploading file using Angular and Node

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I'm having a headache trying to upload files to a Node server from an Angular 6 app. I have the following route handler in the Node app:

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

// Route for /fileupload

//****************************************************************
// Multer module for uploading files
var multer = require('multer');
// set the directory for the uploads to the uploaded to
var DIR = './uploads/';

var upload = multer({ dest: DIR }).single('cloudImg');

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var path = '';

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log('REQ HEADER', req.headers);
        if (err) {
            // An error occurred when uploading
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(422).send("an Error occured")
        }

        // No error occured.
        path = req.file.path;
        return res.send("Upload Completed for " + path);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I use the `multer` module for uploading the file. If I call the API from Postman, everything works fine:

[image]

But if I send the file from the Angular app, the Node server crashes giving this error: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined*.

I've realised that Postman sets this content-type header:

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------719034023986440712074389'
```

I'm pretty sure that the error happens because the Node server is expecting another type of data and it can't create the `req.file` object. I know how to set the `content-type` header, but how could I generate the `boundary` field? Or, is there any way to tell Angular httpClient methods to autogenerate the header for this case?

Thanks,

Comment: are you submitting your file as formData ?  try this  const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);

Comment: Hi! Yes, this is what I do:

    `let formData = new FormData();
        
    formData.append('cloudImg', file);
    
    return this.httpClient.post(url, formData)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );`